# Why mysql server is not starting on Solaris 10?

Tags: mysql

My production server is down due to error on `Mysql`:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (95)
```

Also in my production log it shows the following error:

```
Started GET "/" for 50.18.57.7 at 2013-06-20 08:21:27 +0000

Mysql2::Error (Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (146)):
```

I have tried many options like:

`"svcs *mysql* "`

Also try using:

```
svcadm refresh|disable/enable|restart mysql
```

But nothing happens. My precious data is lost. My production server of rails application is down.

In My rails application I am using:

```
Ruby 1.9.2p180 
Rails 3.0.5 
Phusion Passenger version 3.0.17 
Apache version 2.2.19 
Mysql version 5.5.13
```

In my rails application.

Comment: Can you check your MySQL log? What does it say when you try to start MySQL?

Comment: restarting mysql resolved the issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its working fine in my case by rebooting machine.

Sometime because of some issue like space or any corrupt file. It may be occur.

Try below command and check mysql connection.

```
reboot
```